# Controller doesn't find resolve method

Tags: angularjs, routes, resolve

I'm trying to get some config settings from an API before loading my view so I don't get a billion interpolation errors from trying to use undefined data. The app doesn't crash because of the errors but I need to get rid of the errors nontheless.

I figured I'd use a resolve and wait for the config method to resolve before loading the view but I'm unable to get the data to my controller so that I can use it there. I've been looking at other questions and apparently this is the way you should do it.. What am I doing wrong exactly?

The issue is **not** in the `api` factory, the `api.getConfig()` returns a promise of the `$http.get` request to the external API just fine so I won't include the function snippet here.

In my routing:

```
.when('/:category/top_rated', {
  templateUrl: 'views/pages/results.html',
  resolve: {
    'isAuth': ['fbRefs', function(fbRefs) {
      return fbRefs.getAuthObj().$requireAuth();
    }],
    'getConfig': ['api', function(api) {

      api.getConfig().then(function(data) {
        return data;
      });
    }]
  }
})
```

Then in my controller I inject it like this:

```
core.controller('MainCtrl', ['getConfig', function(getConfig) {

  getConfig.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });

}]);
```

However this throws a `$injector:unpr` error. Why can't it find the resolve method?

Comment: Could You bind controller to when statement? controller: 'MainCtrl',resolve /* ... */

Comment: @cyan My template uses another controller so I'm unable to do that. I tried that anyway but still get the same error.

Comment: something with dependency injection problem

Comment: Where is controller declared? Doesn't seem to be declared in routing where it needs to be

Comment: @charlietfl It sits on my html tag. I have tried declaring in controller too but doesn't do anything.

Comment: doesn't make sense having it on html tag when route is for loading a view in ng-view

Comment: @charlietfl It does when having more than one controller in the template. I've had issues declaring it in the route when having multiple controllers before so trying to avoid it now. Still the issue isn't there like I've said.

Comment: But controller is probably initialized before the route the way you are doing it. `resolve` is asynchronous also if controller is on html tag would be initialized for every route and injection would certainly fail on every other route

Comment: @charlietfl Like I've said, I've tried it your way also.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should be declared in the router, otherwise the controller has no context where 'getConfig' is coming from, thus an injector error.

```html
.when('/:category/top_rated', {
  templateUrl: 'views/pages/results.html',
  controller: 'MainCtrl',
  resolve: {
    'isAuth': ['fbRefs', function(fbRefs) {
      return fbRefs.getAuthObj().$requireAuth();
    }],
    'getConfig': ['api', function(api) {

      api.getConfig().then(function(data) {
        return data;
      });
    }]
  }
})
```